# Reopening a 48/2(9+3) question (ambiguous order of operations)?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, closed-questions, re-open

There was an internet meme started last year about ambiguously written arithmetical expressions leading to arguments for different possible values.  Of course this is not a good place to host pointless arguments, but this is a place where people can be directed to definitive confirmation of the ambiguity of such expressions as $48/2(9+3)$, with the highest voted answer to [this post from April last year](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33215/what-is-48293) being a good example.

Yesterday [a duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175385/simple-maths-problem-made-hard-simpsons-style) was asked, and it was closed as a duplicate.  However, it was closed as a duplicate of a question that is also closed, so this does not leave a place to post an answer.

I am in favor of reopening the older version, [What is 48÷2(9+3)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33215/what-is-48293), and have cast a vote to do so.  I think that "protecting" the question to block new users from answering is a good idea.

If you think that the question should be closed, why?

---

<sub>Incidentally, I had voted to close the older question, but if I remember correctly, I voted to close it as a duplicate of an even older question which I had answered, but instead the older question was merged into the newer one.  Regardless, I am now in favor of reopening.</sub>

Comment: It may be that the closing reason is not fitting very well, but I don't think the question should be *left* open. I don't have a particularly good argument for it now, and I cannot guarantee I will have one later. It just doesn't feel like this question fits.

Comment: I wonder if the votes on this meta question mean "I agree/disagree with reopening" or "This is a good/bad question that is/is not worth discussing".

Comment: I think we should have a canonical version of this question, so that we can use it to close other questions of this type. So I will cast the final vote to reopen if someone casts a 4th vote (it's now at 3). Ping me here if you do.

Comment: @Bill, I just cast the 5th vote.

Comment: I've protected the question, too.

Comment: ...and within minutes of reopening, a close vote was cast on it. Huh.

Comment: @Gerry Thanks. Alas, it's already attracted another close vote. I added a [comment there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33215/what-is-48293#comment404840_33215) referring to this meta question. Please upvote it so folks see it.

Comment: @J.M. See above.

Comment: There are currently 4 close votes, 1 as off-topic, 1 as too localized, and 2 as exact duplicate.

Comment: ...and the question's closed. How now, brown cow?

Comment: I find it irritating that all the comments to wait with voting were ignored (same with [this instance](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4745/5363)). What's the point of having a meta thread if people don't participate and choose to act autonomously?

Comment: @t.b. Perhaps those who voted to close didn't see my comment linking here, since it requires expanding the comments (currently the comment has 4 votes, which is too low to be shown unexpanded).

Comment: Yes, I did not see the note about the meta thread until after I voted to close (and I didn't think to look at the date of the question to see that it is old).

Comment: FWIW I am content with the change to the question being closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

Given that there are already answers to the question that I think are sufficient, I don't yet see the motivation for re-opening.  Also, the question that was re-opened is a localized duplicate of [Do values attached to integers have implicit parentheses?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16502/do-values-attached-to-integers-have-implicit-parentheses)

Comment: I had mentioned that question in [a comment there,](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33215/what-is-48293#comment71458_33215) but it appears to have gone mostly unnoticed among the many other comments.

Comment: Thank you.  Regarding the first point, I do not think that judging the answers to be sufficient is a good reason to close a question, or to keep a question closed.  Regarding the second, I can understand considering those close enough to close the later one as duplicate.  I don't know what you mean by "localized" here. I don't think either question really generalizes the other, but they are very similar.  Perhaps a generalized version to capture "abstract duplicates" would be a good compromise?

Comment: The main rationale for re-opening (in the post above) seems to be that with the question closed "this does not leave a place to post an answer." But there are already answers, including one with 40+ upvotes. Personally, I would consider whether the existing answers are sufficient when thinking about whether th question needs to be reopened.  Closed questions are still visible, along with their answers. I don't think the question needs to be deleted, but at the same time I am not sure that more answers are needed.

Comment: +1 Carl.  "Closed" does not mean it is a bad question.  "Closed" means we do not need any more answers.

Comment: @GEdgar That's the first I've ever heard of "closed" being interpreted that way. I don't think one should ever close a question simply because "we don't need any more answers". Some of the best answers to questions arrive much later, e.g. when experts on a topic join the site. If those questions were closed for the reason you mention, we would not have many of these beautiful answers.

Comment: In this particular case I am not holding my breath for more experts to answer the question. I do think that we can sensibly  distinguish between questions in that way.

Comment: @Bill: Who is this mysterious expert on the correct order of calculating this? What does he have to say that Gerry did not say already?